# function for transferring data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm having a problem on how getting onclick value of another component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where are you rendering that button.js file

- If you call YourButton on the same List component then you can just set a prop and pass it down.

`handleClick(letter) { this.myLetter = letter; }`

```
render() {
`<YourButton letter={this.myLetter} />`
}
```

And inside YourButton you will have this.prop.letter available.

- If YourButton is not a child, then you will have to get the prop on the parent:

  handleClick(letter) {
  this.props.myParentClickEvent(letter)
  }

Then on the parent:

```
myParentClickEvent(letter) {
this.myLetter = letter;
}
```

And then pass it down to any children you want as a prop.

This second step is a bit more complicated so I recommend you to first read the documentation to completely understand how props work on React as it is an essential part if you want to continue working with it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Call your button component over here and pass your function through props to button component.

function should be:->

```
handleClick(letter) {
     return letter;
}

//button component
<button click={this.handleClick} value="getLetterValue" />
```

Through this you will get the value of letter.
Hope this will resolve your issue, if won't than you can contact me again. Its all my pleasure to help you.